# React JS, Boostrap, how to activate srollspy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a React component which is looks like this:

```
function NavBar(props) {
    return (
        <nav id="mainNav" className="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top affix-top">
            <div className="container">
                <!-- There are some JSX code -->
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Which will be loaded dynamically at certain events.

I have now pure Javascript for browser effects with Jquery and Boostrap:

```
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 51
});
```

Because my Navbar is loading dynamically, this `scollspy` method wont be running. I know that for listening click events for dynamically loading elements we can use something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "selector", function (event) {
    // Some handling code
})
```

Is there any method to make scrollspy work with React?

Comment: Maybe call the `scrollspy`  in `componentdidmount`? ( https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)